# How can we check whether new hook is used or not?

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

There is a very nice and handy way to add new hooks to Prestashop teplates:

```
{hook h='nameOfTheHook'}
```

But how can we check whether this hook is used or not?

I need something like:

```
{if $nameOfTheHook}{hook h='nameOfTheHook'}{/if}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{assign var='nameOfTheHook' value={hook h='nameOfTheHook'}}
{if $nameOfTheHook}{$nameOfTheHook}{/if}
```